# Calling a Dynamically set Function Object Property from within the Object

Tags: javascript

From within my webpage I am creating an object and trying to call a dynamically set function from within it. The dynamic function however, isn't being executed. 
Here is a subset of the Object:

```
var LightBoxLogin = {
    DialogBox: null,
    SuccessFunction: null,
    .......... 
    Login: function(){
        console.log(LightBoxLogin.SuccessFunction) // Displays "TestSubmit()"
        LightBoxLogin.SuccessFunction(); // does nothing, should alert the page
    }
}
```

`LightBoxLogin.SuccessFunction` is set with:

```
function SuperLightbox(functOnSuccess)
{
    LightBoxLogin.SuccessFunction = functOnSuccess;

    if(IsLightboxNeeded())
    {
        LightBoxLogin.Login();
    }
    else{
        alert("Not needed");
    }

}
```

And called like:

```
function TestSubmitHandler ()
{
    SuperLightbox(TestSubmit);
}

function TestSubmit ()
{
    alert('TEST SUBMIT ALL CAPS');

}
```

Let me know if im missing anything.
I just need to execute the function passed as a parameter initially.

Comment: Did you mean `.Login()` instead of `.Show()`? Regardless, what exactly is your problem? If the code is working and you're only looking for feedback, this should be moved to [codereview.SE].

Comment: @Bergi No, I just didnt include the irrelevant functions.  In the comment of .Login() you can see the comment of what is happening.  Essentially it isnt calling the TestSubmit() function, which is what I want

Comment: So after `.Show()`, the `Login` method will be called somewhen? What exactly does the log show where it "*returns the function header expected*"?

Comment: @Bergi I'll edit the comment in-line to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line

```
SuperLightBox(TestSubmit);
```

Use the function name as a String instead:

```
SuperLightBox("TestSubmit");
```

This means in the Login:function() this line:

```
LightBoxLogin.SuccessFunction();
```

Will be replaced with:

```
window[LightBoxLogin.SuccessFunction]();
```

This yields the results I was looking for, but beware; it only works if the desired function is accessible globally in the page.